# Calling a static function given a type name

Tags: c#, reflection, static-methods

I have a string holding a type name. I want to get the type in reflection, and call a static method. 
I want to keep the code simple as possible.
something like this:

```
public class MyClass {    
          static int foo() 
          {
             return 7;
          }; 
}

var MyClassType = Type.GetType("MyClass"); 
// your help here! 
int res = (MyClassType).foo();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the correct binding flags to make this work:

```
// NOTE: Use full name for "MyClass", incuding any namespaces.
var myClassType = Type.GetType("MyClass");
int res = (int)myClassType.GetMethod("foo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to give the method name as string as well? Is there no way to cast it to the MyClass type?

Comment: @Adibe7 Yes, when using reflection you need to specify the method name as a string. (You're talking about "foo" here.) Did you mean "the class name"? If it's really the class then you can just do: `var myClassType = typeof(MyClass);`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
int res = Type.GetType("MyClassType").GetMethod("foo").Invoke(null, null);
```